# How do I get perl -c to throw Undefined or Undeclared function errors?

Tags: perl

Coming from a C++ background, I religiously use the `use strict` and `use warnings` features of Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

$foo = 1; #Throws "$foo" requires explicit package name error

foobar( 1 );
```

The `use strict` construct is immensely helpful to catch errors when you mistype a variable name. Is there an equivalent construct to catch mistyped function names? In the above example, it would be great if there was something like `perl -c` that caught the fact that there is no **foobar**  function available to call. Of course running the script throws an **Undefined subroutine** error, but I would like to catch it sooner.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=391783

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
perl -MO=Lint -cw /path/to/script.pl
```

This uses the [B::Lint module](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Lint).

Answer (score 7):

The module [Sub::StrictDecl](https://metacpan.org/module/Sub::StrictDecl) does what you are looking for, and with lexical scope.

> This module provides optional checking of subroutine existence at
>   compile time. This checking detects mistyped subroutine names and
>   subroutines that the programmer forgot to import. Traditionally Perl
>   does not detect these errors until runtime, so it is easy for errors
>   to lurk in rarely-executed or untested code.
>
> Specifically, where checking is enabled, any reference to a specific
>   (compile-time-constant) package-based subroutine name is examined. If
>   the named subroutine has never been declared then an error is
>   signalled at compile time. This does not require that the subroutine
>   be fully defined: a forward declaration such as "sub foo;" suffices to
>   suppress the error. Imported subroutines qualify as declared.
>   References that are checked include not only subroutine calls but also
>   pure referencing such as "\&foo".
>
> This checking is controlled by a lexically-scoped pragma. It is
>   therefore applied only to code that explicitly wants the checking, and
>   it is possible to locally disable checking if necessary. Checking
>   might need to be turned off for code that makes special arrangements
>   to put a subroutine in place at runtime, for example.

Answer (score 6):

Seeing `ikegami`'s Answer reminded me that [perlcritic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlcritic) can identify undeclared subs, but you need to install the [Perl::Critic::StricterSubs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl::Critic::StricterSubs) policy, which is not part of the core `Perl::Critic` distribution.

> perlcritic -4 mycode.pl
>
> Subroutine "foobar" is neither declared nor explicitly imported at
>   line 10, column 1.  This might be a major bug.  (Severity: 4)

Answer (score 2):

Perl cannot possibly know at compile time that there won't be a sub to call once the sub call is reached, so `-c` cannot possibly tell you that.

[`perlcritic`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlcritic) is a tool designed to scan Perl code and *guess* at possible problems like this one.  The Perl::Critic::StricterSubs `perlcritic` rule checks for this problem.